# Microsoft Azure graph returns incorrect metadata

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Microsoft azure graph endpoint wrong metadata response.
This is a random behavior, I tried on couple of domains each there is difference in behavior.

Correct return values :

```
<EntityType Name="DirectoryObject" OpenType="true">

    <Key>
      <PropertyRef Name="objectId" />
    </Key>
    <Property Name="objectType" Type="Edm.String" />
    <Property Name="objectId" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="deletionTimestamp" Type="Edm.DateTime" />
    <NavigationProperty Name="createdOnBehalfOf" Relationship="Microsoft.DirectoryServices.DirectoryObject_createdOnBehalfOf" ToRole="createdOnBehalfOf" FromRole="DirectoryObject" />
```

Incorrect return values:

```
<EntityType Name="DirectoryObject" OpenType="true">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="objectId" />
        </Key>
        <Property Name="objectType" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="objectId" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="deletionTimestamp" Type="Edm.DateTime" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="createdOnBehalfOf" Relationship="Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Microsoft_DirectoryServices_DirectoryObject_createdOnBehalfOf_Microsoft_DirectoryServices_DirectoryObject_createdOnBehalfOfPartner" ToRole="createdOnBehalfOf" FromRole="createdOnBehalfOfPartner" />
```

You can see the difference in "FromRole" of the NavigationProperty . One has "createdOnBehalfOfPartner" one has "DirectoryObject" for the same NavigationProperty.

Anyone have any idea of this strange behavior ?